# Unable to delete a .mp3 file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, text-to-speech

I am unable to remove a file using os.remove() using the following code,

```
import pygame
from pygame.mixer import *
import os
from pygame import mixer

def play_music(music_file, volume):
    with open(music_file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(spoken_text['AudioStream'].read())
        f.close()

    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(music_file)
    mixer.music.play()
    #pygame.mixer.init()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(): 
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
    else:
        os.remove(music_file)
music_file = "C:/CBot/output.mp3"
volume = 0.4
play_music(music_file, volume)
```

The following error is shown:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/CBot/output.mp3'
```

Comment: You just need `pygame.mixer.music.stop()` before the delete

Comment: @ChatterOne should I use `pygame.mixer.music.stop()` before os.remove()  in else part?

Answer (score 1):

The file cannot be deleted because it is currently in use by your application. You have to unload the music file. The comments to your question mention that you need to call `pygame.mixer.music.stop()`. This is wrong. See the documentation of [`pygame.mixer.music.stop()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.stop):

> Stops the music playback if it is currently playing. It **won't unload** the music.

You have to call [`pygame.mixer.music.unload()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.unload):

> This closes resources like files for any music that may be loaded.

```py
pygame.mixer.music.unload()
os.remove(music_file)
```

Comment: yes this is the right answer. thnak you..